# Derby-database is becoming slow after half an hour

Tags: java, database, performance, derby

First of all, sorry for my vague title, but I dont know how to explain it in another way.

The problem lies here:

My application is using a embedded database (apache derby). Works fine, pretty fast, till after 30 minutes or so. After that it takes more time to load SELECT queries than normally. It takes up to 15 seconds, while normally it takes up to 1 second. Is this normal? Because I honestly don't know where I should begin for looking, if you know what I mean. I have two classes which take care of my queries: one with result, one without result.

As it only takes more time if I call a query with result, here is my class:

```
public class QueryLauncherResult extends SwingWorker<ResultSet, Void> {

private Connection conn = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
protected String query;
public ResultSet result;
public AbstractModel model;
JFrame frame;
private JPanel  loadingBar;

public QueryLauncherResult() {

}

public void setLoadingBar(JPanel  bar) {
    loadingBar = bar;
}

public void setModel(AbstractModel model){ 
    this.model = model;
}

public void setConnection(Connection conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

private Connection getConnection() {
    return conn;
}



@Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground() throws SQLException {
        if(loadingBar == null) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
                loadingBar.setVisible(true);
        }

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        return result;
}


@Override
protected void done() {

    model.result = result;
    model.update();

    if(loadingBar == null) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
            loadingBar.setVisible(false);
    }


}





}
```

EDIT:

So, what i've tried by now:

```
    @Override
protected ResultSet doInBackground() throws SQLException {
        if(loadingBar == null) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
                loadingBar.setVisible(true);
        }

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        //stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        result = stmt.executeQuery();
        //conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        return result;
}


@Override
protected void done() {

    model.result = result;
    model.update();





    if(loadingBar == null) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
            loadingBar.setVisible(false);
    }


}
```

There is still no sign of performance. if i close the stmt or resultset in the done() method, it gives me an error that my result set isnt open.

Comment: You should close each `Statement` and each `ResultSet` you create.

Comment: And do i need to do that in the method done? or? Because I read the result in another class.

Comment: If i close the statement then i get an error that my resultset isnt open.

Comment: Resources for getting started analyzing the performance of a database project are here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Sure that the preparestatements makes the queries faster, but that wasn't the problem here.

The problem was like this. The 'model' was still updating old views, while the GUI only showed the new views, ofcourse. I'm deleting the old views now when I refresh - with refresh i mean (SELECT *) queries, add the new views in my model and update them afterwards.

Application doesn't have any issues anymore. Always fast!

Thanks guys!

Comment: My derby is always updating slow. Can you post your solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Manual tuning derby for perfromance improvement](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/tuning/). One ideal way is to use PreparedStatement to make use of derby query Caching

> **Use prepared statements with substitution parameters** 
>   In Derby, as with most relational database management systems, performing an SQL request has two steps: compiling the request and executing it. When you use prepared statements (java.sql.PreparedStatement) instead of statements (java.sql.Statement) you can help Derby avoid unnecessary compilation, which saves time. In general, any query that you will use more than once should be a prepared statement.

Comment: So, every SELECT statement should be prepared? Because i tried it before and it didnt work.

Comment: It works now, but it isnt fast. See my edit.  Maybe i need to close the stmt, but i dont know where, because it gives me an error that my resultset isnt open.

Comment: So, did some testing. The problem only occurs when i first do some queries who doesnt have a resultset, like: INSERT etc... After a couple of these ones, the select queries become alot slower. Wich is wierd, because the classes who run the queries are two seperate classes.

Comment: Is it possible, because I use a query where I join some data, that after I add a new record to the database, the connection becomes slower? Because it stays fast if i never do a insert query or something.

Comment: come out from your project, write separate query then loop it and execute continiously, see performance.